# Looking for a software to record streaming videos (not screen recorders)

Tags: screen-recording, streaming, video-recording

I'm looking for a software that records the actual streamed videos from any site.

I'm not looking for a screen recording software.

loved Jaksta because it records the actual streaming videos unlike screen recording software. It also detects streaming videos automatically which is nice. I just can't use Jaksta on that machine so I'm looking for a different software.